# GCSFuse installation in Docker in GCloud failing

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcsfuse

I'm running a command that worked until yesterday, and works locally on my local Docker, to install gcsfuse version 0.28.1:
E: Version '0.28.1' for 'gcsfuse' was not found

I tried it on the google cloud console too, and got the same error there.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Here's the original command:
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s` 
&& echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list 
&& curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - 
&& apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcsfuse=0.28.1 \

Comment: Can you please add in your original post the full command that you ran?

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below commands on Google Cloud Shell as per this [document reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md#ubuntu-and-debian-latest-releases) and I was able to install GCSFuse successfully.

```
Add the gcsfuse distribution URL as a package source and import its public key using :

export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

Update the list of packages available and install gcsfuse using :
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcsfuse

(Ubuntu before wily only) Add yourself to the fuse group, then log out and back in using :
sudo usermod -a -G fuse $USER
exit
```

I also found a line in this document which says “The following instructions set up apt-get to see updates to gcsfuse, and **are supported for the bionic, artful, zesty, yakkety, xenial, and trusty releases of Ubuntu, and the jessie and stretch releases of Debian. (Run lsb_release -c to find your release codename.) Users of older releases should follow the instructions for other distributions below.**

So you should also try and find the release codename first. If you are a user of an older release then these commands might not work for you. For that, follow the instructions/commands of installing older distributions, which is clearly differentiated and specified in this [document link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md#older-releases-and-other-distributions)

Comment: I need an older version.  I'm just not sure why the apt-install broke, after working for several months.

Comment: Please specify your Operating System and GCSFuse version you want to install. Have you tried the commands for older releases from the [document link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md#older-releases-and-other-distributions) I provided in the answer?

Comment: Version '0.28.1' and OS is debian/

Comment: Follow the steps at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md#older-releases-and-other-distributions. Also see a bug report has been mentioned in Old versions of Debian, that causes /dev/fuse to repeatedly lose its permission settings. If you find that you receive permissions errors when mounting, even after running the usermod instruction above and logging out and back in, you may need to fix the permissions:

sudo chmod g+rw /dev/fuse, 
sudo chgrp fuse /dev/fuse

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it was your formatting but it looks like it was missing the release variable in your commands. Please try with the commands below:

```
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s` && \
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list && \
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - && \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install -y gcsfuse=0.28.1 -V
```

If it does not work, here is the repo with all gcsfuse releases:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/releases/tag/v0.28.1